# Can an instance variable belong to multiple classes?

Tags: oop

I have been looking at classes in OOP and was curious to how this works.

For example, lets say I have a product. The product is a bike.

There could be a class for the product stock and a class for the products details e.g. colour etc.

I could use classes within each other for this such as a class called product and within it it contains both the stock and details for the product(bike)

Or could i have an instance called bike that is made from both

e.g.

Stock bike = new Stock();
details bike = new details();

or would the instance bike have to be renamed for them e.g.

Stock stockbike = new Stock();
details detailsbike = new details();

Hopefully that makes sense. Essentially I just wondered whether one instance keyword can belong to 2 classes or does the instance name in this case bike have to be changed so it can belong to more classes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`Stock bike = new Stock(); details bike = new details();`

Not quite sure what you're asking... but I think what you're asking is if you can have 2 variables with the same name and in the same scope.  Generally, no.  You didn't mention your language but let's assume Java.

```
public void test() {
   String test = "123";
   String test = "123";  // Error
   Integer test = 123;  // Also an error

   Stock bike = new Stock();
   Details bike = new Details();  // Error
}
```

One case where you COULD have the same name... although discouraged... is a local variable with the same name and type a variable of higher scope

```
public class Test {
   private String myString;

   ...

   public void test() {
       String myString = "123";  // Warning and discouraged
    }
}
```

Comment: exactly what I wanted to know. sorry for the lack of details.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an OOP rule that describes this.

In some language, you can have multiple inheritance, though. So you can have a class Bike which inherits from both Stock and Details. And after you've defined that class, you can just make a normal instance from it.

Reading material: [Wikipedia on Multiple inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance). Also describes languages that implement this, one way or another.